# Get value held by Android EditText field using the identifier

Tags: android, android-edittext

I got the id dynamically as an integer using getIdentifier(). I want to be able to get the value held by the EditText field using the integer id.

**I should add this method i'm writing is not within an Activity, it's in a seperate non-Activity class.**

Comment: " I put that in instead of the R... " means?

Comment: I put the int id as an argument to findViewByID() instead of for example R.id.name and it doesn't recognise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String value = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext)).getText();
```

If you are using a separate class, you should pass a reference to the EditText into that class. First get the reference

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(getResources()
        .getIdentifier("edittext", "id", "com.yourpackage"));
```

then pass it to your other class, and use `getText` on it there. Make sure you only try to access the EditText while the Activity is active.

There is a warning for the `getIdentifier` method, so you should only be using it if you have no other choice:

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Comment: I got the id using getIdentifier(). I put that in instead of R.id.edittext and it won't let me use the findViewByID() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext)).getText().toString;
```

`toString()` is required, as `getText()` returns editable

Comment: I got the id using getIdentifier(). I put that in instead of R.id.edittext and it won't let me use the findViewByID() method.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
String ed1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.value)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: I got the id using getIdentifier(). I put that in instead of R.id.value and it won't let me use the findViewByID() method.

Comment: I don't think you can get the id inside the layout via getIdentifier? It is used to get the id of the resource folder like(R.layout.xxx,R.drawable.xxx).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(your_editText_id);
CharSequence text = et.getText();
String textS=text.toString();
```

Comment: I got the id using getIdentifier(). I put that in instead of the R... and it won't let me use the findViewByID() method.

Comment: Try context.findViewById(your_editText_id);

assuming you got some pointer to your application/activity context.